# Implementation of mergesort / merge-method

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort

I tried to implement the mergesort algorithm.
The merge method might be wrong.
Here is my code so far:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    mergesort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
}   

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mergesort(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    if (j - i < 1)
        return;
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;
    mergesort(list, i, mid);
    mergesort(list, mid + 1, j);
    merge(list, i, mid, j);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(List<T> a, int p, int q, int r) {
    int half = q - p + 1;
    int otherhalf = r - q;

    List<T> left = new ArrayList<T>();
    List<T> right = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        left.add(i, a.get(p + i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < otherhalf; i++) {
        right.add(i, a.get(q + i + 1));
    }

    int leftindex, rightindex, resultindex;
    leftindex = rightindex = resultindex = 0;

    while (leftindex < left.size() || rightindex < right.size()) {

        if (leftindex < left.size() && rightindex < right.size()) {

            if (left.get(leftindex).compareTo(right.get(rightindex)) < 0) {
                a.set(resultindex, left.get(leftindex));
                resultindex++;
                leftindex++;
            } else {
                a.set(resultindex, right.get(rightindex));
                resultindex++;
                rightindex++;
            }
        } else if (leftindex < left.size()) {
            a.set(resultindex, left.get(leftindex));
            resultindex++;
            leftindex++;
        } else if (rightindex < right.size()) {
            a.set(resultindex, right.get(rightindex));
            resultindex++;
            rightindex++;
        }   
    }
}
```

I tested it.
As an input I choose `[5, 6, 1, 4]`.

The output was: `[1, 1, 4, 4]`:

It seems that I did not get to the position 5 and 6 in merge method.
So I think, I have to increment something, but I do not know where?
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: I did my homework, but I can't find the mistake. I'm sorry, that I aksed.

Comment: It's hard to see whats going wrong, so I think it's best is to start debugging and go through your code step by step.

Comment: When you dont understand what your code is doing, don't ask other people to tell you that. First try to use a debugger, or to add simple print statements. It also helps to run such algorithms with small example data "manually", using just a pen and a piece of paper. Understand how the sorting should work, then try to find out where your implementation does something different than that. When all of that doesnt work out, *then* it is time to ask for help ...

Comment: Ok I will do that in future.

Comment: But just for the record: your question contains all necessary elements (the code, and and example data with actual output). So you did a good job there!

Comment: Hey @Steven33 Welcome to StackOverflow, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, you will be able to write more precise questions and a quick solution then. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `resultindex` is initialized to `0` instead of `p`.

Here are some other notes:

- it would be simpler to use the index of the first excluded value for the right limit instead of that of the last element. It avoid `+ 1` adjustments that may cause off by one errors.
- the comparison should be `if (left.get(leftindex).compareTo(right.get(rightindex)) <= 0)` instead of `<` to ensure stable sort.
- the test `else if (rightindex < right.size())` is redundant.
- you can reduce the number of tests by writing 3 loops: one for as long as both halfs have members, then one to copy the rest of the left half, finally one to copy the rest of the right half.
- your variable names are not idiomatic in java.

Here is a corrected version:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    mergesort(list, 0, list.size());
}   

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mergesort(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    if (j - i < 2)
        return;
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;
    mergesort(list, i, mid);
    mergesort(list, mid, j);
    merge(list, i, mid, j);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(List<T> a, int p, int q, int r) {
    int leftLen = q - p;
    int rightLen = r - q;

    List<T> left = new ArrayList<T>();
    List<T> right = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < leftLen; i++) {
        left.add(i, a.get(p + i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rightLen; i++) {
        right.add(i, a.get(q + i));
    }

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int resultIndex = p;

    while (leftIndex < leftLen && rightIndex < rightLen) {
        if (left.get(leftIndex).compareTo(right.get(rightIndex)) <= 0) {
            a.set(resultIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
            resultIndex++;
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            a.set(resultIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
            resultIndex++;
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
    while (leftIndex < leftLen) {
        a.set(resultIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
        resultIndex++;
        leftIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex < rightLen) {
        a.set(resultIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
        resultIndex++;
        rightIndex++;
    }   
}
```

Furthermore, there is no need to save the right half because its elements never get overwritten before they are copied. Indeed copying the rest of the right half is useless because these elements are already in place.

Here is a simplified version:

```java
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(List<T> a, int p, int q, int r) {
    int half = q - p;
    List<T> left = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        left.add(i, a.get(p + i));
    }

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = q;
    int resultIndex = p;

    while (leftIndex < half && rightIndex < r) {
        if (left.get(leftIndex).compareTo(a.get(rightIndex)) <= 0) {
            a.set(resultIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
            resultIndex++;
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            a.set(resultIndex, a.get(rightIndex));
            resultIndex++;
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
    while (leftIndex < half) {
        a.set(resultIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
        resultIndex++;
        leftIndex++;
    }
}
```

Further simplifying the code:

- a dynamic `List` is not required for the `left` array,
- some local variables can be omitted as well
- a combined test makes the last loop useless.

Here is the simplified but potentially less readable code:

```java
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(List<T> a, int p, int q, int r) {
    int i, half = q - p;
    T[] left = new T[half];

    for (i = 0; i < half; i++)
        left[i] = a.get(p + i);

    for (i = 0; i < half; ) {
        if (q == r || left[i].compareTo(a.get(q)) <= 0)
            a.set(p++, left[i++]);
        else
            a.set(p++, a.get(q++));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much:) Finally it is working. I made a really stupid mistake.

Comment: @GhostCat: good point, answer updated. although I don't particularly like this convention: I would favor much shorter names for a small function like this.

Comment: Short names are okay for short scopes. If you follow clean code, you would probably further dissect this code and end up with many small methods. With pretty short variable names in them.

Comment: @GhostCat: further dissection added, simpler but a bit cryptic.